# Pulsar rotation

Tags: angular-momentum, astrophysics, neutron-stars, pulsars

## Pulsars are said to be spinning objects from which two beams of radiation emanate in opposite directions.

Observed pulse rates range from on the order of one pulse per second to hundreds of pulses per second. The standard model suggests then that these objects are rotating between about 60RPM to upwards of **4000RPM**. The angular velocity at the surface of some of these objects would be astronomical (on the order of millions or tens of millions of times greater than at the surface of earth).

Then we are told that these objects are gravitationally bound together as their surface rotates at **about a billion miles per hour**.

**Given that gravity is such a weak force, how can it hold such an object together?**

*(Postscript: this is all ignoring the conclusion one must draw that every observable pulsar must be pointing directly at earth for us to observe it)*

Comment: Have you not considered their density? Pulsars are extremely compact bodies with densities exceeding  10^17 kg/m^3

Answer (score 4):

Gravity is indeed strong enough to hold the neutron star together. In the rotating frame of reference
$$ \frac{GM}{r^2} - r\omega^2 > 0$$
and gravitational acceleration exceeds centrifugal acceleration.

A pulsar will have a mass of about $1.4M_{\odot}$ and a radius of 10 km. The fastest pulsars have a rotation period of about $10^{-3}$ s.

Thus the sum of gravitational and centrifugal acceleration at the equatorial surface is $-1.9\times 10^{12}+4\times 10^{11}=-1.5\times 10^{12}$ m/s$^2$ inwards.

Note this is a rough calculation, since General Relativity with an appropriate metric is more apt than Newtonian gravity at the neutron star surface.

The fact that a pulsar can hold itself together despite enormous centrifugal forces is evidence that the gravitational field and hence $M/R^2$ is very large. Combine this with other evidence that $R$ is very small ($\sim 10$ km), for example from the rapid variability on timescales of a milli-second, and we deduce that pulsars must be at least stellar-mass objects.

*Postscript: It is a truism that we can only see phenomena that we can see. The observable pulsars have a beam that sweeps across the Earth. The ones that don't, which are thought to be the majority, we can't observe.*